# What are use cases for Recursive CTEs?

Tags: cte, recursive

I am looking for examples of *why* you would use a recursive CTE, but the dozens of examples I have found in my web searching basically reduce to two:

- Generating a sequence
- Iterating through an employee hierarchy

I did find one example where a recursive CTE is used to split a string by commas, which is by far the most interesting (db<>fiddles: [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c5d96914670daf9719088963b1c6d3d), [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c5d96914670daf9719088963b1c6d3d)).

Are there examples of recursive CTEs which are not basically one of the above?

Comment: [Generate a mandelbrot set](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set)

Comment: Side point: it's faster to generate a sequence using an inline tally table (using virtual tables and cross-joining them). See eg https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1

Comment: @Charlieface - it **constantly** amazes me that no other major server has [taken up | cloned | copied...] PostgreSQL's [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-srf.html) functionality - available since version 8.0 (2005).

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW I suggested to Itzik Ben-Gan in his [Number Generator series of articles](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/05/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-5), that he'd spent more time on it than it would have taken the SQL Server team to implement it

Answer (score 4):

Here are three applications which don't involve either generating a sequence or iterating through an employee hierarchy:

1. [How can I calculate all grouping permutations of an input string in SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/302389)
2. [Sum all unique values from previous dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/270521)
3. [Get top two rows per group efficiently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/286627)

Paul White has a neat use for [finding distinct values](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan).

---

> Iterating through an employee hierarchy

This is one example of a broader type of problem called *tree problems*. Recursive CTEs are great at solving tree problems in an efficient and more relational manner as opposed to iteration.

Other similar examples that exhibit parent-child relationships are BOM (Bill of Material) explosions in the manufacturing industry, actual parent-child-grandchildren relationships in ancestry problems, any other hierarchy problem, etc. Tree problems are somewhat commonplace. Recursive CTEs are very useful (in a quality over quantity of uses).

Check out explainextended.com - you can use RECURSIVE CTEs to play board games, draw [stereograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy) and Mandelbrot sets (as well as other fractals), resolve various patterns from the game of life, write a GIF decoder... SQL is like poetry,  one is only limited by one's imagination!

Answer (score 1):

## Complex Problems

You can use recursive sub queries to [solve a sudoku puzzle](https://technology.amis.nl/it/solving-a-sudoku-with-one-sql-statement/)

Oracle syntax

```
with x( s, ind ) as
( select sud, instr( sud, ' ' )
  from ( select '53  7    6  195    98    6 8   6   34  8 3  17   2   6 6    28    419  5    8  79' sud from dual )
  union all
  select substr( s, 1, ind - 1 ) || z || substr( s, ind + 1 )
       , instr( s, ' ', ind + 1 )
  from x
     , ( select to_char( rownum ) z
         from dual
         connect by rownum <= 9
       ) z
  where ind > 0
  and not exists ( select null
                   from ( select rownum lp
                          from dual
                          connect by rownum <= 9
                        )
                   where z = substr( s, trunc( ( ind - 1 ) / 9 ) * 9 + lp, 1 )
                   or    z = substr( s, mod( ind - 1, 9 ) - 8 + lp * 9, 1 )
                   or    z = substr( s, mod( trunc( ( ind - 1 ) / 3 ), 3 ) * 3
                                      + trunc( ( ind - 1 ) / 27 ) * 27 + lp
                                      + trunc( ( lp - 1 ) / 3 ) * 6
                                   , 1 )
                 )
)
select s
from x
where ind = 0
```

### Other

I would imagine you could use it for any iterative process like curve fitting.

But, I find it more efficient to offload the curve fitting procrss to something like R.

Answer (score 1):

> Iterating through an employee hierarchy

At the point when you say this the question becomes basically useless.

A hierarchy is a modeled a *tree*. A tree is a subtype of a directed graph. All *graphs* can be serialized into a table, and queried through a recursive CTE. Why? Because *recursion* is a tool that allows you to navigate a graph. And you can't do that with SQL. You can query for a row that relates to another row statically: but you can not query for a row that relates to another row abstractly.

That it is an *"employee"* hierarchy is irrelevant. All graphs will require Recursive Queries when the relationship between nodes is unknown or dynamic.

For example, [*"threaded messages are hierarchical too"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167579/2639). As is general ledger, a family tree, and all kinds of stuff.